# In perl, backreference in replacement text followed by numerical literal

Tags: regex, perl

I'm having trouble with a backreference in my replacement text that is followed by a literal. I have tried the following:

```
perl -0pi -e "s/(<tag1>foo<\/tag1>\n\s*<tag2>)[^\n]*(<\/tag2>)/\1${varWithLeadingNumber}\2/" file.xml
perl -0pi -e "s/(<tag1>foo<\/tag1>\n\s*<tag2>)[^\n]*(<\/tag2>)/\g{1}${varWithLeadingNumber}\g{2}/" file.xml
```

The first of course causes problems because ${varWithLeadingNumber} begins with a number, but I thought the `\g{1}` construct in my second attempt above was supposed to solve this problem. I'm using perl 5.12.4.

Comment: Are you sure your problem isn't with the shell?  I'd enclose the script in single quotes except for the part collecting the shell variables, just to cut down on the number of backslashes to worry about.

Comment: I just tried, for example, `perl -0pi -e 's/(<tag1>foo<\/tag1>\n\s*<tag2>)[^\n]*(<\/tag2>)/\g{1}25\g{2}/' file.xml`, and the result was the same. The replacement text ends up being `g{1}25g{2}`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `\1`, `\2`, etc in the replacement expression is wrong. `\1` is a regular expression pattern that means "match what the first capture matched" which makes no sense in a replacement expression. Regular expression patterns should not be used outside of regular expressions! `$1`, `$2`, etc is what you should be using there.

After fixing `\1`, you have

```
perl ... -e'... s/.../...$1$varWithLeadingNumber.../ ...'
```

That said, I think `varWithLeadingNumber` is supposed to be a shell variable? You shouldn't have any problems if it's a Perl variable. If you're having the shell interpolate `varWithLeadingNumber`, the problem can be fixed using

```
perl ... -e"... s/.../...\${1}${varWithLeadingNumber}.../ ..."
```

Note that you will have problems if $varWithLeadingNumber contains "$", "@", "\" or "/", so you might want to use a command line argument instead of interpolation.

```
perl ... -pe'
   BEGIN { $val = shift; }
   ... s/.../...$1$val.../ ...
' "${varWithLeadingNumber}"
```

You could also use an environment variable.

```
export varWithLeadingNumber
perl ... -pe's/.../...$1$ENV{varWithLeadingNumber}.../'
```

or

```
varWithLeadingNumber=varWithLeadingNumber \
    perl ... -pe's/.../...$1$ENV{varWithLeadingNumber}.../'
```

---

If you did have a `\1`

```
s/...\1.../.../
```

you can avoid the problem a number of ways including

```
s/...(?:\1).../.../
```

Comment: This works if I do `perl -0pi -e 's/(<tag1>foo<\/tag1>\n\s*<tag2>)[^\n]*(<\/tag2>)/${1}'${varWithLeadingNumber}'${2}/' file.xml. Thanks.

Comment: Only for limited values of `$varWithLeadingNumber`. I recommend against that.