# Javascript backreference followed by number

Tags: javascript, regex

If I had a regular expression with, say 13 capturing groups, how would I specify a replacement string that contained the first backreference followed by the literal '3'?

```
var regex = /(one)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)(11)(12)(13)/;
"one2345678910111213".replace(regex,"$13");
//Returns "13". How do I return "one3"?
```

The closest question I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7559473/1726343), but it pertains to perl and did not include a hardcoded literal.

Also had a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on MDN, but there was nothing explicitly stated or demonstrated in the examples.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good catch! The only solution I've been able to come up with is:

```
var regex = /(one)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)(11)(12)(13)/;
"one2345678910111213".replace(regex, function(match, $1) { return $1 + "3"; } );
```

---

**EDIT** I looked up the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) and it looks like this is possible without a callback. Some RegExp replacement engines -- Python, for example -- have a `\g` construct (for "group"), where you can use something like `\g{1}3` in the replacement string; but JavaScript just uses `$nn`. That is, if you've got more than 9 capturing groups, you can use a two-digit back reference to remove the ambiguity, like so:

```
"one2345678910111213".replace(regex, "$013" );
```

Comment: +1, but that's still a callback. Does that mean it is impossible to do this with a string argument?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to do it without using a callback: I tried various things, but this was the only one that worked. Perhaps it's not possible with a simple string.

Comment: The solution to use $013 doesn't seem limited to cases where you have more than nine capturing groups.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add a concise answer for future reference:

Backreferences have at most two digits, so to use backreference #1 followed by a literal numeral, call it "01" instead of "1":

```
"one2345678910111213".replace(regex,"$013");
```