# RegEx backreference followed by a number in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I want to search for a specific pattern which contains a numeric "1" and replace it with the same string followed by the numeric "2". But if I call `$12` then the output is the literal "$12". The regex engine seemingly tries to find the memory slot 12, but I intended to address the memory slot 1, and then write "2".

I tried to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvg3B/) but this doesn't reproduce the error, so apparently it has something to do with my editor. I am using Dreamweaver CS6. If not with Dreamweaver then maybe my Dreamweaver settings.

Also, I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248365/javascript-backreference-followed-by-number) which refers to my exact same problem – but the answer provided there doesn't work for me. `$012` just writes "$012". I guess the Dreamweaver RegExp engine is peculiar like that.

Any ideas?

*EDIT:*

Given the example text …

```
This is item 1
This is house 3
```

… and the pattern `((?:item|house) )\d`

what I tried | what I'm getting

```
$12     | $12
$012    | $012
\g{1}2  | \g{1}2
$g{1}2  | $g{1}2
$1&#50; | item&#50;   // or "house"
${1}2   | ${1}2
"$1"+2  | "item"+2
```

The desired result is always:

```
This is item 2
This is house 2
```

Because it was asked: yes, I am *sure* that the RegExp checkbox is activated and yes, I am *sure* that I'm in the Code view, not the Design view. I always work in Code view.

My Dreamweaver is CS6 Version 12.0 Build 5861.

Comment: can you try this : `"$1"+4`

Comment: Can you give us a before / desired output sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known bug in Dreamweaver. Fortunately, there are workarounds.

For argument's sake, let's say you are looking for letters and want to append a `2`.

**Method 1**

I tested the following in Dreamweaver CS6.

**Input:**  `abc`

**Search in code view:** `([a-z]+)`

**Replace:** `$1&#50;`

**Output in code view:** `abc&#50;`

**Output in design view:** `abc2`

Note that the output in code view is `abc&#50;`, but because `&#50;` encodes 2, on the web page you see `abc2`

**Method 2: Two-step approach**

Same search.

**Replace:** `$1SOMETHINGDISTINCTIVE`

Then search for `SOMETHINGDISTINCTIVE` and replace with `2`

**Finally**

Of course some would argue that the real workaround is to work in Komodo IDE (or whatever editor they fancy), but that is not your question. :)

Comment: Hearing that it's a well-known bug gives me hope. But are you sure this works? I'm getting the literal output "$1&#50;".

Comment: I tested it in CS6 before posting the answer. Are you sure: (1) the regex box is checked in the find panel? (2) you searched in `code view` as specified by my answer? (If you search in `design view`, DW will escape the ampersand so you will have a literal `&#50;` Don't know about the `$1` literal though, different version?

Comment: Ooooooh! The "2" is the output in _design view!_ Then that's not a helpful answer: I'm trying to replace class names and such.

Comment: Of course, that would have worked. Simple and obvious. Sometimes I'm really blind. I ended up doing it by hand …

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the Test String i.e. the string to match or select, is

aabbbccbbbaacc2

Case 1: Using Backreference for Matching or Selecting

---

Find/Search:
(a+)(b+)(c+)\2\1\3\d

Case 2: Using Backreference for Match or Select & Replace

---

Say I Expect The Result as 
aacc9bbb

Find/Search:
(a+)(b+)(c+)\2\1\3\d

Replace With:
\1\039\2
or
\1$039\2

So It's NOT \3 but \03 or $03, when it is followed by a numeric character, in the Replace With Field.