# Matching the first occurrence of underscore followed by a digit and replacing set of matches in html

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following strings:

```
foo_0_13
foz[0][bar][]
far_0
```

I have a convention, and need to match from strings like `foo_0_13` and `far_2` the underscore and the digit following, example `_0` or `_2`... And for any string with structure `foz[0][bar][]` or `foz[3]` I need to match `[0]` or `[3]`

I have tried `((\_\d)|\[\d\])` but this matched `_0_1`, how can I make it match only `_0`?

I need to find only the first occurrence of the "underscore-digit" combination.

**Second part:**

If I have an html division with multiple occurrence of `_0` and `[0]` as

`<div id="foo_0_13" name="bar[0][xxx][]"> <p id="par_0">Test</p> </div>`

and I need to replace all the these occurrence with `_1` so that the html becomes

`<div id="foo_1_13" name="bar[1][xxx][]"> <p id="par_1">Test</p> </div>`

how can I elaborate this to get the desired html knowing that am using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following regex replace.

```
var res = str.replace(/("[a-z]+[_[])\d+/g, '$01' + '1'); // 1 = new digit
```

[See regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nR2xO7/2) or [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1e6sw0dp/2/)

In the replacement  I used `'$01' + '1'` just to visualy separate the backreference group 1 from the newly added digit. Acutally the replacement would be `$11` or `$011` where the last [to be preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13248365/5527985).

Answer (score 1):

Start at the beginning of your string. Match everything ungreedily in a non-capturing group until you encounter either of the patterns to match.

```
(?:^.*?)(_\d|\[\d\])
```

Demo and breakdown: https://regex101.com/r/cT6qX2/1

Comment: @KAD please ask a new question if you have a new question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an implementation that is pulling groups you can isolate the possible second underscore and digit outside of the group.

Without knowing the regex implementation or language it's hard to give a perfect answer.

Example:

```
(_\d)_*|(\[\d\])
```

Comment: This seems good but I have to capture 2 groups rather than 1, I think @timgeb s approach is better. As for the language, I am using javascript

Comment: I like @timgeb s approach as well but note that it is one capturing group, some combination of the two seems in order