# Seperate backreference followed by numeric literal in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, backreference

I found this related question : [In perl, backreference in replacement text followed by numerical literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559473/in-perl-backreference-in-replacement-text-followed-by-numerical-literal) 
but it seems entirely different.
I have a regex like this one

```
s/([^0-9])([xy])/\1 1\2/g
                   ^
              whitespace here
```

But that whitespace comes up in the substitution.

> How do I not get the whitespace in the substituted string without having perl confuse the backreference to `\11`?

For eg. 
`15+x+y` changes to `15+ 1x+ 1y`.
I want to get `15+1x+1y`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\1` is a regex atom that matches what the first capture captured. It makes no sense to use it in a replacement expression. You want `$1`.

```
$ perl -we'$_="abc"; s/(a)/\1/'
\1 better written as $1 at -e line 1.
```

In a string literal (including the replacement expression of a substitution), you can delimit `$var` using curlies: `${var}`. That means you want the following:

```
s/([^0-9])([xy])/${1}1$2/g
```

The following is more efficient (although gives a different answer for `xxx`):

```
s/[^0-9]\K(?=[xy])/1/g
```

Answer (score 8):

Just put braces around the number:

```
s/([^0-9])([xy])/${1}1${2}/g
```

Comment: This even works if you are using `s{}{}g` syntax (surprisingly).

Comment: @Sridhar Sarnobat, When using `{}`, `[]` and `()` as delimiters, you can safely nest the delimiters. e.g. `m{ x{3} }x` and `m{ { | } }x` are ok, but `m{ } | { }x` and `m{ [{] }x` are not ok. Escaping would be needed.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'm glad you told me